# How to adjust multiple views based on json response

Tags: iphone, json, uiview, storyboard, swift3

I have an image as attached. Based on the JSON response, I have to hide/show the views.

[image]

For eg: In the attached image, if "Mobile Lines With No Usage" is not there in JSON response, the view should be hidden and get adjusted in the view.

Similar to the image attached, I have 4 views in total in the `ViewController` with multiple subviews inside each view.

So basically, based on response I need to show/hide and adjust the views accordingly.

Is this possible?

Comment: I guess "Mobile Lines With No Usage" and the other four texts is a label! Isn't it so?

Comment: yes. Everything is dynamic. Need to adjust views based on response